# Помогите ускорить вставку данных в таблицу

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте, есть таблица **tst_ex1** содержащая 2 поля: ***id** int identity(0,1)*, ***gui** uniqueidentifier null*. И таблица **tst_ex2** содержащая поле ***gui2** uniqueidentifier null*. Из таблицы **tst_ex1** содержащую 3 миллиона строк хочу вставить миллион строк в таблицу **tst_ex2**, но разработанный мной алгоритм выполняет данную операцию крайне медленно(вставка данных будет происходить больше недели), т.к. большую часть времени идёт проверка всех 3 млн. строк на соответствие условия ***where*** (код ниже):

```
use Test
go

declare @b int = 0;

while @b < 1000000

begin
     insert into dbo.tst_ex2 (tst_ex2.gui2) select tst_ex1.gui
     from dbo.tst_ex1 where tst_ex1.id = @b;
     set @b += 1;
end;
```

Помогите ускорить процесс вставки. Читал про **bcp**, но на практике как его использовать так и не понял.

Comment: `insert into dbo.tst_ex2 (tst_ex2.gui2) select tst_ex1.gui from dbo.tst_ex1 where tst_ex1.id<100000` не пробовали?

Comment: 1. Индекс-то какой-нибудь на таблице `tst_ex1` есть, или это безиндексная куча? 2. Вставляйте не по одному, а кусками, скажем, по 10000 (`... where tst_ex1.id between @b and @b + 10000`).

Comment: Если во второй таблице есть индексы, то можно (скорее даже нужно) попробовать их отключать перед вставкой и снова включать после.

Comment: > insert into dbo.tst_ex2 (tst_ex2.gui2) select tst_ex1.gui from dbo.tst_ex1   > where tst_ex1.id<100000 не пробовали?

Comment: @YuraIvanov я не указал в условии, что вставку обязательно в цикле нужно делать, а так да - запрос намного быстрее идёт))

Comment: @Yaant да, это была безиндексная куча, переделал  и таблицу(добавил кластерный индекс), и запрос как вы подсказали, сработало всё за 12 секунд, спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Anatol во второй таблице индексы отсутствовали, спасибо за совет, в будущем, в работе, учту.

Answer (score 2):

Основной способ ускорения такого запроса - это убедиться, что на поле id у вас существует индекс. По логике таблицы это поле может быть также сделано PRIMARY KEY с кластерным индексом.

Если требуется еще сильнее ускорить вставку, то следующий шаг - это секционирование таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо **minamoto**, так и сделал с **id**. Ещё для ускорения использовал вставку которую советовал **Yaant**.